# In group sort table join a another table use first func

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

First I use window func sort my table `t1` by `charge_time` and put `t1` join with `t2` on `user_id`.
I want to get first record if `t1` has more than one record. 
I use `first` func to implement this

```
    _df = ss.sql("""
                    SELECT 
                        t1.user_id,
                        t1.pay_id,
                        t1.sku_mode,
                        t1.charge_time,
                        t1.exchange_type_t01,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.user_id ORDER BY t1.charge_time)
                    FROM 
                        {} t1 
                    WHERE 
                        t1.refund_state = 0
                """.format(exchange_info_table))
    _df.createOrReplaceTempView('d_exchange_info')

    df = ss.sql("""
            SELECT 
                first(t1.sku_mode) AS sku_mode,
                first(t1.exchange_type_t01) AS exchange_type_t01,
                first(t1.user_id) AS user_id,
                first(t1.pay_id) AS pay_id,
                first(t1.charge_time) AS charge_time,
                first(t2.has_yxs_payment) AS has_yxs_payment,
                first(t2.has_sxy_payment) AS has_sxy_payment,
                first(t2.has_cxy_payment) AS has_cxy_payment,
                first(t2.has_sxy19_payment) AS has_sxy19_payment,
                first(t2.sxy19_join_time) AS sxy19_join_time,
                first(t2.yxs_join_time) AS yxs_join_time
            FROM
                d_exchange_info t1
            JOIN
                analytics_db.md_day_dump_users t2
            ON 
                t2.the_day = '{}'
                AND t1.user_id = t2.user_id
            GROUP BY
                t1.user_id
    """.format(st))
```

I use `first` func but I will get an unstable record by sort with charge_time record.
If records more than one, sometimes I get a one sometimes a get another

Why it happen and how to fix it?
It's a sparksql prob or my sql have some prob?

PS: I already know how to fix it with another way but I want to know why first func  not effective.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a lot about spark, but from the documentation:

```
The function is non-deterministic because its results depends on order of rows 
which may be non-deterministic after a shuffle.
```

Your window function seems to be producing a row_number, but you are not using that anywhere.

You either need to sort your result set or if your intention is to use the row number you generated then add `where row_number=1`. You also have to name your row_number column unless it is done explicitly by spark.

Comment: Yes. Exactly I use this way to fix it. Where is this doc you found?  I just find out a func doc like this """Aggregate function: returns the first value in a group.
    The function by default returns the first values it sees. It will return the first non-null
    value it sees when ignoreNulls is set to true. If all values are null, then null is returned """ from spark doc.

Comment: Doc was the standard apache doc pages. This is the link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#first-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-